# Which lifecycle events are called by fixture.detectChanges()

Tags: angular

I am using final release of Angular2.

Which lifecycle events does `fixture.detectChanges()` call and in what order?

Where are the docs on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Component Lifecycle order:**

ngOnChanges,
ngOnInit,
ngDoCheck,
ngAfterContentInit,
ngAfterContentChecked,
ngAfterViewInit,
ngAfterViewChecked,

And ngOnDestroy.

You can read the full explanation here:
[Lifecycle sequence](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html)

Comment: This is not really what the initial question is about

Answer (score 2):

With `fixture.detectChanges()`I see following in the console (with Angular 7.1.1 and Jest / Wallaby):

```
console.log ../../../wallaby/server.js:20
  ngOnDestroy
console.log ../../../wallaby/server.js:20
  ngOnInit
console.log ../../../wallaby/server.js:20
  ngDoCheck
console.log ../../../wallaby/server.js:20
  ngAfterContentInit
console.log ../../../wallaby/server.js:20
  ngAfterContentChecked
console.log ../../../wallaby/server.js:20
  ngAfterViewInit
console.log ../../../wallaby/server.js:20
  ngAfterViewChecked
```

`ngOnChanges` is not invoked and I am calling it manually.

Without `fixture.detectChanges()` there is no lifecycle hook invoked.

Answer (score 1):

I had a unit test which called fixture.detectChanges() only. The lifecycle events that fired that I was interested in were ...

> LOG: 'start detecting changes'
>
> LOG: 'ngOnChanges'
>
> LOG: 'ngOnInit'
>
> LOG: 'ngDoCheck'
>
> LOG: 'end detecting changes'

If anyone has a fuller answer please provide one - thanks

Comment: Hi Did you got solution which life-cycle occur call detect changes , for me first time all calls sequentially, when i change the instance behind and call detect changes again , then which life cycle hook calls